# Firebase InApp Messaging open a deeplink only once in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-in-app-messaging

I'm having difficulty using In-App Messaging and I do not know how to solve this problem. I configured the button action with the URL of a Deeplink mapped in the application, but when I click this button, no action happens.

My problem is with the message action button. In the campaign I configured the action to run a deeplink. This action only works once. If I submit a new test of this campaign, the button action doesn't run anymore!

I've already incorporated some logs and breakpoints and I definitely can't see the difference between the first run and the following runs. The button action simply doesn't work with deeplinks or universal links. The only action that occurs by clicking the button is to dismiss view with the message defined in the campaign.

Comment: Perhaps if you posted your relevant code someone would give some insight to the issue. Everything else would be endless conjecture.

Comment: @Barns the In-App Messaging implementation does not have any code insertion, based on the SDK documentation itself.

Comment: Fetching the same issue. Have you found any solution? Please share with me. Thanks.